# emacs indentation style in file local variables

Tags: indentation, file-local-variables

I am using emacs 24.5 and I ran into a problem with file local variables.

I am working on a git project where file local variables are set like:

```
/* -*- Mode:C++; c-file-style:"gnu"; indent-tabs-mode:nil; -*- */
```

However, they seem to be using unindented namespaces.
But when I indent the whole buffer I also get namespaces indented.

Is this the desired default behaviour? How can I override the namespace indendation?

I tried the answer mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619853/emacs-override-indentation

But I want to do this only for the current project, thus I tried to put it in a .dir-locals.el file.

I tried:

```
((cc-mode (eval add-hook 'c++-mode-hook  (lambda() (c-set-offset innamespace [0])))))
```

I also tried:

```
 ((cc-mode . (c-offsets-alist . ((innamespace . [0])))))
```

I also tried changing the style in my dir-locals.el, but none of them seem to override the file local setting. Is this a priority issue of file local variables?

Comment: Please do not post the same question both here and at StackOverflow. Either is OK, not both. Please choose one and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: "Is this a priority issue of file local variables?" -- Yes, file-local variables absolutely take precedence over directory-local variables (exactly as they should -- the other way around makes no sense).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do it, i don't know if it is elegant, but it works quite well.

I created a new MAJORMODE-local-vars-hook by adding this to my init.

```
;; Provide a new MAJORMODE-local-vars-hook
 (add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook 'run-local-vars-mode-hook)
 (defun run-local-vars-mode-hook ()
   "Run a hook for the major-mode after the local variables have been processed."
   (run-hooks (intern (concat (symbol-name major-mode) "-local-vars-hook"))))
```

And then i added the c++-mode-local-vars-hook in my dir-locals

```
(nil . (eval . (add-hook 'c++-mode-local-vars-hook  (lambda () (c-set-offset 'innamespace 0)))))
```

I guess just adding a c++-mode hook did not do the job because mode hooks execute before local variables are processed.

I don't know why the other method failed though.

Comment: I'm going to assume a reference to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5148435

Answer (score -1):

[editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org) may be a good and universal solution for problems like this. Emacs plugin also [exists](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-emacs) and works good.

With editorconfig you control project settings not only for Emacs, but also for different supported IDE and editors.

Comment: Yes, but editorconfig doesn't provide enough level of control to do this.